# Null check operator used on a null value creating path in flutter

Tags: flutter, path, flutter-hive

When i am creating a path for hive database it's showing an error.
"Null check operator used on a null value"

```
void main() async{
  Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();


  runApp(const EntryWidget());
}
```

Comment: can you post the complete code that you have tried?

Comment: basically i need to create a hive database table for furture using. So that i need to initialize Hive and hive ask for a path parameter.So when i add this line It showed me this error

Comment: What is the stack trace?  Can you post a minimal, reproducible example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wait for the widget to initialize as it must be searching before that and getting null value somewhere in the library. Try using below line of code before the await command.

```
   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
   Directory appDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
```